# Deleting last few hours of zeitgeist history like in Firefox?

Tags: 11.04, zeitgeist, history

I want to open secret files on Ubuntu Natty and after my work delete the history of open files or any recorded activity during last:

- one hour
- three hours
- one day
- one week
- etc...

how can I do this, with GUI or at least in terminal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install `Activity Journal` for this. The events are shown daywise and by Morning, Afternoon and Evening wise. Just right click on those events and select delete.

Snapshot:
[image: Activity Journal view]

---

Alternativly [Stefano Candori](https://twitter.com/#!/devcando) (Activity Journal maintainer) has worked on a [`BIG FAT ERASER` concept](http://devcando.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/gaj-getting-some-love/).

The work has landed in the source code, but it will be available in next `Activity Journal` release.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try Activity Log Manager. It is a GUI that lets you configure Zeitgeist. Among other things, it lets you delete the last X minutes of your history.

You have to add the zeitgeist PPA prior to install it, because it is not in the Ubuntu repositories:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:zeitgeist/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install zeitgeist activity-log-manager
```

And then, open it searching for Activity Log Manager in the dash.

Source: [UbuntuGeek](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/install-zeitgeist-and-activity-log-manager-for-zeitgeist-on-ubuntu-using-ppa.html)