# Clear "Most Frequently Used" in "Applications"?

Tags: 11.04, zeitgeist

In the new Ubuntu, can you clear "Most Frequently Used" in "Applications"?

Answer (score 1):

Like this: [Deleting last few hours of zeitgeist history like in Firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31918/deleting-last-few-hours-of-zeitgeist-history-like-in-firefox)

Answer (score -2):

Open up a terminal window and execute the following commands,

- To clear recent documents, use:

  `rm ~/.local/share/zeitgeist/activity.sqlite zeitgeist-daemon --replace`
- To prevent new items from being created run the following command,

  `echo -n > ~/.recently-used.xbel`

  `sudo chattr +i .recently-used.xbel`
- If you want to restore it back, then

  `sudo chattr -i .recently-used.xbel`

Comment: Surely you can just shut off zeitgeist instead of chattr'ing a file?

Comment: First `rm` command also has some side effects. This not only clears all the `Most Frequently Used` applications but all your activity log which includes document open/close. Tomboy notes open/close/create/delete and lot more things.